# Count elements with certain class exists after a click action

Tags: jquery

I have 2 "Halls" and a link which hides the hall.
After click, I want to count how many elements with `machine-on` exist. I tried the following but it doesn't work.. any ideas?

For example, when I click Hide Hall 1, the counter should return 1.

```js
$('.hide-hall').click(function() {

  $(this).closest('.hall').addClass('d-none');

  var counterOn = 0;
  $('.hall :not(.d-none)').children('.btn').each(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('machine-on')) {
      counterOn++;
    }
  });

  console.log("counterOn = " + counterOn);

});
```

```css
.d-none {
  display: none;
}

.machine-on {
  color: blue;
}

.machine-off {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="hall">
  <p> HALL 1 <a href="#" class="hide-hall" title="Hide hall">Hide</a></p>
  <span class="btn machine-on">Machine 1</span>
  <span class="btn machine-on">Machine 2</span>
  <span class="btn machine-off">Machine 3</span>
</div>
<br/><br/>
<div class="hall">
  <p> HALL 2 <a href="#" class="hide-hall" title="Hide hall">Hide</a></p>
  <span class="btn machine-on">Machine 4</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could count the elements a lot easier by selecting all `.hall` that do `.not` have `.d-none` and count the amount of `.find('.machine-on')` using `.length`.

```js
$('.hide-hall').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.hall').addClass('d-none');

  console.log($('.hall').not('.d-none').find('.machine-on').length);
});
```

```css
.d-none {
  display: none;
}

.machine-on {
  color: blue;
}

.machine-off {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="hall">
  <p> HALL 1 <a href="#" class="hide-hall" title="Hide hall">Hide</a></p>
  <span class="btn machine-on">Machine 1</span>
  <span class="btn machine-on">Machine 2</span>
  <span class="btn machine-off">Machine 3</span>
</div>
<br/><br/>
<div class="hall">
  <p> HALL 2 <a href="#" class="hide-hall" title="Hide hall">Hide</a></p>
  <span class="btn machine-on">Machine 4</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The space before `:not` causes this not to work.

```
$('.hall:not(.d-none)').children('.btn').each(function() {
```

Full code:

```js
$('.hide-hall').click(function() {

  $(this).closest('.hall').addClass('d-none');

  var counterOn = 0;
  $('.hall:not(.d-none)').children('.btn').each(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('machine-on')) {
      counterOn++;
    }
  });

  console.log("counterOn = " + counterOn);

});
```

```css
.d-none {
  display: none;
}

.machine-on {
  color: blue;
}

.machine-off {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="hall">
  <p> HALL 1 <a href="#" class="hide-hall" title="Hide hall">Hide</a></p>
  <span class="btn machine-on">Machine 1</span>
  <span class="btn machine-on">Machine 2</span>
  <span class="btn machine-off">Machine 3</span>
</div>
<br/><br/>
<div class="hall">
  <p> HALL 2 <a href="#" class="hide-hall" title="Hide hall">Hide</a></p>
  <span class="btn machine-on">Machine 4</span>
</div>
```